# Allow user zoom in android textview

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to allow users to zoom contents of a textview in android application.

Right now I have created an application where users not able to zoom in or zoom out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no. Text is static. If you want to zoom it you have to use a GestureListener and programmatically change the text size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp` instead of `dp` as your font size units so that the text scales depending on the device settings.

Comment: yes sp does help. but wanted to give users more control as I haven't tested my app on possible screen sizes